# Wordpress menu anchor tag not work when click but works as "new tab"

Tags: wordpress

I have menu problem at wordpress website which one page template. I have 6 menus at top level menu. 5 of these anchor tag which goes to specific ids at home page. One of them goeas to blog page.

There is no problem at home page. Menus works well. But there is problem at interior pages. Menus ,which goes to specific div at home page, are not working. I click it and then mouse cursor switch hand to arrow pointer but not go anywhere. It is wierd that when layout is changed to mobile, menus works properly.

I have specified menu links at admin dashboard to www.domain.com/#divid and divs structure like below

```
<div id='divid'>...</div>
```

I have tried deactivate all plugins but not works. I have tried clear browser cache many times but not work. I am going to crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Add the links as `/#divid`, not `#divid`.

Comment: Yeah i have already added with /#divid. I discovered that opened Chrome Development Console and went to Event Listener of anchor click event, i saw a element whşch is related with jQuery. When hover on a element a remove option appear near this. When i click it and remove that click element, which is related with jQuery, hrefs works. 

Really i couldnt understad what is the problem